# Laravel Scheduled Commands randomly stop running (but scheduled jobs keep working)

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-scheduler

I have scheduled some commands and it randomly stops working. They work for ~10 days and stop randomly, and if I restart the server, they start working again for another ~10 days.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {

   $schedule->command('dump:database')
                ->hourlyAt(0)
                ->environments(['production'])
                ->thenPing("https://example.com/hash");

   $schedule->command('other:command')
          ->daily();

   $schedule->job(new ECheckScheduleChecks())
        ->daily()
        ->environments(['production']);
}
```

The weird thing is the scheduled Job keeps running.

Also the `->thenPing()` gets triggered even though the code inside the commands does not run.

I don't see any issue in the logs and schedule:run works fine.

This issue is driving me crazy. Any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue.... what you end up doing?

Comment: I ditched using scheduled commands and I run scheduled jobs. If you figure out how to overcome it, please let me know too